# To show there exists a unique function $u \in C^{1}(\mathbb{C^n})$ that satisfies $(\bar{\partial u})=f$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, several-complex-variables

Assume $n \gt 1$. Let $f$ be a $(0,1)$ form in $\mathbb{C^n}$, with $C^1$-coefficients and compact support $K$, such that $\bar{\partial} f=0$. Let $\Omega_{0}$ be the unbounded component of $\mathbb{C^n}-K$. I need to show there exists a unique function $u \in C^{1}(\mathbb{C^n})$ that satisfies $(\bar{\partial u})=f$ as well as $u(z)=0$ for every $z \in \Omega_{0}$

Let $f=\sum f_j(z) d\bar{z_j} $. Let's define for $z \in \mathbb{C^n}$ $$u(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\mathbb{C}}f_{1}(\lambda,z_2,..,z_n) \frac{d\lambda \wedge d\bar{\lambda}}{\lambda-z_1}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\mathbb{C}}f_{1}(\lambda+z_1,z_2,..,z_n) \frac{d\lambda \wedge d\bar{\lambda}}{\lambda}$$

I am trying to evoke the following proposition here:

> Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a bounded open set. Suppose $f \in C^{1
> }(\Omega)$, $f$ is bounded and $$u(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\Omega} \frac{f(\lambda)}{\lambda-z} d\lambda \wedge d\bar{\lambda}, (z \in \Omega).$$ Then $u \in C^{1}(\Omega)$ and $\bar{D}u=f$.

From the above mentioned Proposition, $\bar{D_1}u=f_1$. I also think that $u \in C^1(\mathbb{C})$ follows from here but I am not sure about it. Now since we have $(\bar{\partial f})=0$, for $2 \le j \le n$, $\bar{D_j}f_1=\bar{D_1}f_j$, so that $$(\bar{D_j})u(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\mathbb{C}}(\bar{D_j}f_{1})(\lambda,z_2,..,z_n) \frac{d\lambda \wedge d\bar{\lambda}}{\lambda-z_1}$$(why can I take the differential inside: because the function is bounded ??)
$$=(\bar{D_j})u(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\mathbb{C}}(\bar{D_1}f_{j})(\lambda,z_2,..,z_n) \frac{d\lambda \wedge d\bar{\lambda}}{\lambda-z_1}$$

It should follow from here that the last statement is equal to $f_j(z)$. I am thinking of this proposition (but not able to find out why)

> $$\text{Let $\Omega$ be a bounded region in $\mathbb{C}$, with smooth oriented boundary $\partial\Omega$. If $u \in C^1(\bar{\Omega})$, then we have $u(a)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial \Omega}\dfrac{u(\lambda)d\lambda}{\lambda-a}-\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Omega}\dfrac{\bar{D}u(\lambda)d\bar{\lambda}\wedge d\lambda}{\lambda-a} $}$$

Suppose $\bar{D_j}u=f_j$ for $1 \le j \le n$, then we are done with the first part. This also shows that $u$ is holomorphic in $\Omega_0$(as the derivatives vanish there). I have no idea how to show that $u(z)=0$ in $\Omega_0$( take $|z_1|$ large in the first equation??)

Also why this theorem fails when $n=1$??

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Why do you need to show this, is it a homework problem?

Comment: I was trying to understand "bochner martin" formula.  have been reading the book "function theory in the unit ball of c^n" by Rudin.  And I was unable to get this portion.